# Opening a .pak file using fopen and making that file apply to a const unsigned char* (C++)

Tags: c++, function, fopen, libpng, unsigned-char

I'm trying to upload a file (.pak file) using fopen, read it and make it equal `blockStorage`.

What I'm doing right now doesn't work, I think because pfile.data() doesn't even exist (it's left over from something I was trying and stopped doing because I was doing it completely wrong) and it's a pointer anyway so it doesn't make sense.

I want to know how I can get my file to equal blockStorage, so I can run it through the function I call `BlockDecompressImageDXT5`. I haven't included the function because it is fairly long and I don't think it really applies to my current problem.

I'm pretty amature with c++, and I've been struggling with this problem, figuring out different versions of it until finally I've found the right path and I know how to procced.

```cpp
int main() {

    FILE* pFile;
    pFile = fopen("C:\Users\erast\Desktop\encrypt.pak", "r");
    
    unsigned long x = 0;
    unsigned long y = 0;
    unsigned long width = 512;
    unsigned long height = 512;
    const unsigned char* blockStorage = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(pFile.data());
    unsigned long* image = new unsigned long[width * height];

    BlockDecompressImageDXT5(width, height, blockStorage, image);
```

I've been reading documentation and asking around for a while now, still pretty confused on how I could get my uploaded file to equal `blockStorage`. I've been working on this project for around a month now, and it's been extremely hard with my basic C++ knowledge. I've been learning but learning takes time.

Comment: You need to open the file in binary mode and use the `fread` function.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm uploading my pak file correctly (changing "r" to "rb")  and after reading some `fread` documentation I think I'm reading it correctly as well. Unfortunately I'm still confused on how I should assign the data I get from reading my file to `blockStorage`

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have figured out a way to make this work. I've stopped using fopen, because a person told me it was C, and helped me move to a more C++ method.

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include "func.h"

using namespace::std;

const std::string readFile(const std::string&& fileName) noexcept {
    // taking file as inputstream
    std::ifstream file(fileName);

    if (file) {
        // reading data
        std::ostringstream ss;
        ss << file.rdbuf();
        return ss.str();
    }
    else {
        // file wasn't found
        return "Missing file!";
    }
};

int main() {

    // cout << fileReader("./Client/index.xhtml");

    // Variables for file upload and read

    // upload my pak file
    const std::string pFile = readFile("encrypt.pak");

    // obtain file size (*in characters*):
    const size_t lSize = pFile.size();

    // copy the file into the buffer:

    // My variables for my functions 
    const unsigned long x = 0,
        y = 0,
        width = 512,
        height = 512;

    const char* const blockStorage = pFile.c_str();

    unsigned long* const image = new unsigned long[width * height];

    using ustring = unsigned char*;

    // The function I'm calling
    BlockDecompressImageDXT5(
        width,
        height,
        reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char* const>(blockStorage),
        image
    );
}
```

I hope this may help anyone who is trying to upload a .pak file as a const unsigned char in the future.